# I downloaded php-sdk-master package and it's dependencies and trying to test Change_creditcard.php

Tags: php

I trying to authonticate from authorized.net iam getting the following warning
could you please help me.

> C:\wamp\www\sdk-php-master\sdk-php-master/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Annotation/Type.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') .

Iam using php:3.5 and running wamp server in windows.
Autoload .php

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom SPL autoloader for the AuthorizeNet SDK
 *
 * @package AuthorizeNet
 */

spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    static $classMap;

    if (!isset($classMap)) {
        $classMap = require __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classmap.php';
    }

    if (isset($classMap[$className])) {
        include $classMap[$className];
    }
});
```

This is my include  classmap.php page 
getting error line is 
'JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type' => $vendorDir . '/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Annotation/Type.php',

Comment: Is that *really* your error message? A path (with a trailing quote but no leading one), followed by the words "for inclusion", followed by your include path? The error message is obviously badly-formatted, incomprehensible nonsense, and while I'm not *certain* that it isn't an error that PHP or anything in the PHP ecosystem actually spits out, I'm immediately suspicious that you haven't properly copied the error message.

Comment: This is my error message...but ihv MechantAuthentication Type Class  Fatal error: Class 'net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType' not found Pls help me  ...I was downloaded the above code from https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php site